# Postgres unique date column

Tags: postgresql, date, unique

I wanted to create table with unique date column. Is it possible?

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE senders (
id              bigint  NOT NULL,
number          bigint  NOT NULL,
inserted_at     date    NOT NULL
);
```

I want to be sure I will have unique values per date. For example I can insert `(1, 1, '2017-01-01'),(1, 1, '2017-01-02')` but I can't add then `(1, 1, '2017-01-01')` one more time. I tried using UNIQUE constraints creating table or unique indexes but always I have SQL unique exception.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX senders_unique ON senders (id, number, inserted_at);

CREATE TABLE senders (
id              bigint  NOT NULL,
number          bigint  NOT NULL,
inserted_at     date    NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(id, number, inserted_at)
);
```

Is it possible. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: unique index is the option. If you had error creating it, you probably already have duplicates

Comment: What exactly is the error you got? And for which statement?

Comment: OK. Last time inserting values I used ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING. Without it I figured out that I had additional unique index on number column. Now I works. Sorry my bad